# Masking numbers in PrimeFaces footerText column Datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, number-formatting

I want to display a masked number like this: 1.234.567,89.
The following code already do this:

```
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.value}">
      <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

How can I applly the same mask for a Primefaces datatable in a footerText column as the following code excerpt?

```
<p:columnGroup type="footer">  
  <p:row>  
    <p:column colspan="8" footerText="Grand Total:" />  
    <p:column footerText="#{upbController.totalLosses}" />      
  </p:row>  
</p:columnGroup>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try to place your footerText using *f:facet*. Here is how I used to use it for *p:column*:

```
<p:column headerText="Number of units" >
    <h:outputText value="#{item.units}" />
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:outputText
            value="Total: #{mybean.unitsTotal}" />
        <br />
        <h:outputText
            value="To do: #{mybean.unitsTodo}" />

    </f:facet>
</p:column>
```

I suspect that it would work also for *p:columnGroup* and then you can apply *f:convertNumber* to such *h:outputText*.

#### Update

And here's how works for header facet in header type:

```
<p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
        <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Manufacturer" />
        <p:column colspan="2">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.countValue(bean.order)}">
                    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" currencyCode="PLN" locale="pl_PL" />
                </h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```

and for footer facet in footer type:

```
<p:columnGroup rendered="true" type="footer">
    <p:row>
        <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Manufacturer" />
        <p:column colspan="2">
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.countPieces(bean.order)}">
                    <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###.00" locale="pl_PL"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```

Comment: I used as described, but had no effect: <p:columnGroup type="footer">  
 <p:row>  
  <p:column colspan="8" footerText="GrandTotal:" />
    <p:column>
      <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:outputText value="Total: #{upbController.perdasTotal}" >
          <f:convertNumber locale="pt_BR" />
        </h:outputText>
      </f:facet>
    </p:column>
   </p:row>  
</p:columnGroup>

Comment: I extended my answer with examples that are working for me. Did you check in isolated case that applying locale without specifying desired pattern change the output text at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do thay by using ui param and use converter in it. After that getting that value at p:column footerText

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Numbers) then you can do

```
<p:columnGroup type="footer">
  <p:row>
    <p:column colspan="3" footerText="Total:" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.jan, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.feb, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.mar, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.apr, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.may, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.jun, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.jul, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.aug, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.sep, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.oct, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.nov, '#.00')}" />
    <p:column footerText="#{of:formatNumber(bean.total.dec, '#.00')}" />
  </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```