# <f:convertNumber /> doesn't affect the footerText value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have this column:

```
<p:column headerText="Percent"
    footerText="#{bean.entityTotal.percent}">
        <h:outputText value="#{entity.percent}">
            <f:convertNumber type="percent" />
        </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

the percent mask(`<f:convertNumber type="percent" />`) work very well for the `<h:outputText>`, but the footerText is not affected.
How can i put a mask at this footer without making much effort?

it's not duplicated, because i wanted to know how can i use mask in footerText and the other post doesn't talks about it, talks about using facets.

Comment: i didn't ask why doesn't affect, i'm looking for a solution.

Comment: how can i use footer facet? i don't know!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Masking numbers in PrimeFaces footerText column Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793072/masking-numbers-in-primefaces-footertext-column-datatable)

Comment: @Kukeltje using facet, i'll have to do a lot of things, i was looking for something more simples, but i think there's no way.

Comment: the table i'm working has about 15 columns, i'll have to do more 15 columns to the footer using facets.

Comment: "You can try to place your footerText using f:facet." it's not using the attr footerText="", if you don't know how to do with the attr footerText="" or you know that is impossible, you can talk that you don't know or that's impossible. I know that is simple and fast, but i'm want to know if has to do with the attr footerText=""

Comment: try this @Kukeltje: http://esl.fis.edu/learners/advice/read.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original question was:

> How can i put a mask at this footer without making much effort?

Depending on what your definition of 'much' effort is, the answer one of:

- Not possible
- [Masking numbers in PrimeFaces footerText column Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793072/masking-numbers-in-primefaces-footertext-column-datatable)

And considering the remarks in the comments, the for you unfortunately unwanted single valid answer is:

**Not possible**